# how to open mysqld.log file

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

I am unable to start mysql on centos vmware.

I am trying to see the log file but I cant figure out how to  open the file and see any error messages in it. Can someone show how to open the log file

the file does exist and returned this when I ran

```
 ls -l mysqld.log
```

-rw-r-----. 1 mysql mysql 1279 Apr 21 08:12 mysqld.log

however, when I do this

```
gedit mysqld.log
```

I get this error message in gedit window.

"Could not open the file /var/log.mysqld.log"
"you dont have the permissions n ecessary to open the file."

so how to view contents of this file

here are the contents of my.cnf file if it helps

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried "sudo" command? 
(if you have the super user permission.)

I mean:

```
$ sodu gedit mysqld.log
```

and then input your password.